# Is Visual Studio Express Edition 2010 free?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is Visual Studio Express Edition 2010 free?

On this page: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/ it says it is a set of free tools. But the splash screen at the start says it is only for evaluation purposes. And the about screen has a trial countdown timer counting down the days to when it presumably stops working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is free, quoted from http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/

```
"Express requires that you register 
your evaluation copy within 30 days of installation. Once you've 
entered your Registration Key, the product is free"
```

The registration link is http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/regins/

Comment: That page no longer works although the code you need is 6VPJ7-H3CXH-HBTPT-X4T74-3YVY7

Comment: http://www.filetrig.com/2015/09/microsoft-visual-studio-2010-express-all-registration-product-keys/

Answer (score 1):

The express editions have always been free to use, going back to VS2005. I imagine that will continue, which is just as well since Microsoft eliminated the Standard edition from the 2010 lineup.

Comment: Frankly, the Express edition comes with very good functionality.  Pretty much the only thing you'll miss the the lack of extensibility.